# How to compare different default stack sizes?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory, memory-management

I changed the default stack size of my Linux machine from 8MB to 2MB and i want to compare the amount of memory i have saved with this change . How  can I compare the effect of changes in the system with 8mb stack size and one with 2 mb stack size

Comment: This smells of an off-topic question; especially based on some of your comments in some of the answers. Perhaps you can improve the question a bit for Stack Overflow. And to be clear, Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions.

Answer (score 1):

Write a non-tail recursive function that prints an increasing number such as:

```
void stackOverFlowMe(int i) {
    cout<<i<<"\n";
    stackOverFlowMe(i+1);
}
```

for example in C++ (you can use any language), and see how far it goes. Most programs don't need that much.

Following your comment you can check memory usage in all Linux distributions using `top` in the shell. The first lines have the global info:

```
top - 11:27:46 up 18 days, 21:08, 13 users,  load average: 0.71, 0.23, 0.16
Tasks: 277 total,   2 running, 274 sleeping,   1 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  1.4 us,  0.4 sy,  0.0 ni, 98.1 id,  0.1 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  8105520 total,  1798056 free,  3223720 used,  3083744 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  5192700 total,  5165132 free,    27568 used.  3993932 avail Mem
```

Comment: i wanted to know  how much memory i have saved  by doing this change but when i compare i see the same value in both  the system . if u could give me some  information that will be really great .. thanks

Comment: @ABHINAVKUMAR13BIT0087 See edit for a global picture of your memory. Not sure you would be affected much, depending on what you're running.

Comment: yes i tried  top , free , vmstat , /proc/meminfo  , but i was not able to  find  much difference  . but i will try to go in more depth

Comment: @ABHINAVKUMAR13BIT0087 It really shouldn't save you that much, most normal stuff dosen't use that much stack.

Answer (score 0):

When programs on your linux box run, they add and remove data from the stack on a regular basis as the programs function. The stack size, referes to how much space is allocated in memory for the stack. If you increase the stack size, that allows the program to increase the number of routines that can be called. Each time a function is called, data can be added to the stack (stacked on top of the last routines data.)

Unless the program is a very complex, or designed for a special purpose, a stack size of 8192kb is normally fine. Some programs like graphics processing programs require you to increase the size of the stack to function. As they may store a lot of data on the stack. Below are some commands for changing stack size. Hope this will help.

```
SunOS/Solaris:
==============
    > limit          # shows the current stack size
    > unlimit        # changes the stack size to unlimited
    > setenv STACKSIZE 32768 # limits the stack size to 32M bytes

Linux:
======
    > ulimit -a     # shows the current stack size
    > ulimit -s 32768   # sets the stack size to 32M bytes
```